# One of the positive reals $a,2a,3a,...,(n-1)a$ has at most distance $1/n$ from a positive integer.

Tags: combinatorics

One of the positive reals $a,2a,3a,...,(n-1)a$ has at most distance $1/n$ from a positive integer .
The solution given in the  book is as follows :

> Considering the fractional parts of these numbers we get $n-1$ reals in the interval $[0,1]$. Subdivide this unit interval into $n$ equal parts each of length $1/n$. If one of the $n$ points falls in the first interval then we are finished . Otherwise, two points say ${ia} $ and ${ka}$ fall into the same interval.the point ${(k-i)a}$  is a distance $\leq1/n$ from $0$.

I am not really getting the idea behind the solution . Can anyone please explain it?

Comment: Note:  The proof does appear to be a little bit off.  You have $n-1$ points in $n$ intervals so you could miss one interval without forcing some interval to contain at least $2$ points.  However, if *either* the first *or* the last interval contains a point you are done, so excluding both of those intervals would leave you with $n-1$ points  to distribute amongst $n-2$ interval so indeed one interval would be forced to contain at least two points.

Comment: For example, with $a=\frac 34$ and $n=2$ none of your points lie in the first interval, but you do have a point (the only point) in the last interval which is good enough.

Comment: The proof also says 'positive integer' and then uses $0$, and if $(k-i)a<1/n$, but we have already established that there is no point in the first interval.

Comment: @JMP.  Yes, that's a good point.  With $a=\frac 1{10}$ and $n=5$  none of $\{a,2a,3a,4a\}$ is within $\frac 15$ of a positive integer.

Comment: @lulu  I did not get the part where ot says if one of those points fall in the first interval then we are done? What is the idea behind it? I did not get it....

Comment: If one point , $ka$ , is in the first interval that means the fractional part of $ka$ is within $\frac 1n$ of $0$ which means that $ka$ is within $\frac 1n$ of an integer. As the comments point out, though, that integer might be $0$ so the author ought to have said non-negative instead of positive.

Comment: @lulu can you also explain the part of the last interval ...where it says if the point is at the last interval then we are done ? How is it so?Even if it so, then 2 points lie in same interval hence from there how did we conclude the desired result....

Comment: No big difference between the first and last interval. If you are in the last interval you are near $1$.

Comment: @lulu Even if it so, then 2 points lie in same interval hence from there how did we conclude the desired result....that only implies the distance between those two points lying in the same interval is essentially less than $1/n$  but how did we conclude that the distance between an integer and the difference between two points is less than $1/n$ furthermore if this is true whatsoever then how can the original real number is at a distance $ 1/n $ because we are only considering fractional parts....

Comment: If  the fractional parts of $ka$ and $ja$ are in the same interval with  $k>j$ then the fractional part of $ka-ja$ is in the first or last interval, so that interval wasn't empty after all.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot! Just one more thing we considered fractional parts from the very begining ...but the question specifically asks that the real number is at a distance of $1/n$ from an integer ...so we concluded that the fractional part is $1/n$ from the integer but what about the original real number?....

Comment: Saying that the fractional part is within $\frac 1n$ of an integer is equivalent to saying that the number itself is within $\frac 1n$ of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As presented, the argument is wrong: We have $n-1$ fractional parts (pigeons)  and $n$ parts (holes), hence it is well possible that each pigoen finds a different hole and at the same time leaves the first hole empty.

Rather, the argument should go: If any of the fractional parts is in the first interval $[0,\frac1n)$ **or** in the last interval $[\frac{n-1}n,1)$, we are done. In all other cases, we have $n-1$ fractional parts $\{ia\}$ distributed among $n-2$ intervals $[\frac1n,\frac2n),\ldots,[\frac{n-2}n,\frac{n-1}n)$, hence two, $\{ia\}$ and $\{ka\}$, end up in the same interval. Then $\{|i-k|a\}=|\{ia\}-\{ka\}|<\frac1n$.

Comment: @Franklin If $x\in\Bbb R$, the fractional part of $x$ is $\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\le x$.